# Как разобраться с папками в web приложении Java SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, glassfish

Помогите разобраться с папками в web приложении на SpringBoot, thymeleaf
Сколько видео не смотрел на эту тему, каждый создает свою структуру папок, при этом ни чего не обьясняет (типа так нужно), и когда пытаешься повторить этот проект, то ни фига не работает.
В документации на Spring советуют такую структуру каталогов:
[image: структура каталогов]

а в документации на сервер (GlassFish) советуют такую структуру:

```
|_main
  |_recources 
  |_webapp
    |_WEB-INF
```

Я так понял это прописывается вот здесь:
[image: web]
Как мне лучше сделать, чтобы все работало и не было путаницы с этими каталогами?

1. Оставить шаблоны (css, js и др) thymeleaf в recources а конфиги сервера в webapp
2. или перенести шаблоны thymeleaf в папку webapp, как я понял это можно сделать с помощью настройки:
   spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/webapp/templates/
   но как thymeleaf поймет, что папка static тоже переехала в webapp
3. или пренести WEB-INF в recources измениев его настройки

Подскажите как все это правильно настроить, чтобы уже раз и навсегда разобраться с этом вопросом?

И по поводу второго пункта, если система Windows, как правильно указать путь:

```
.prefix=classpath:/webapp/templates/
```

или

```
.prefix=classpath:.\webapp\templates
```

или

```
.prefix=classpath:..\webapp\templates
```

classpath в моем случает это recources?

Comment: простите, а зачем Вам рекомендации GlassFish? SpringBoot имеет свой встроенный веб-сервер (Apache Tomcat)

Comment: Изначальная структура каталогов в первом варианте является структурой предназначенной для работы с Maven. Без Maven со спрингом вам будет работать немножко тяжко, поэтому вторую показанную структуру можно выкинуть куда-нибудь подальше

Comment: Выбранная структура "Web" во втором случае подразумевает скорее всего работу с Java EE. Java EE и Spring это далеко не одно и тоже, поэтому смысла в ее использовании нет

Comment: я не рекомендую брать рандомную структуру и натягивать ее на другой проект

Comment: если вам нужно понять какую структуру папок использовать посмотрите гайды на официальном сайте Spring'а https://spring.io/guides